# Stochastic noise with known propability density function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, stochastic-calculus, random-process

How can I generate samples for random function, which functional "probability density" is known? When I say "probability density" for random function $\xi(\mathbf{q},t)$, I mean, that there is such a functional $P[\xi(\mathbf{q},t)]$, that all the mean values due to the $\xi$ realizations should be calculated as following path integral:

$\langle A[\xi]\rangle_{\xi}=\int \mathcal{D}\xi \ A[\xi] P[\xi]$.

In my particular case this PDF is the following:

$
P[\xi(\mathbf{q},t)]= \exp \left[- \int d t \int \frac{d^{2} q}{(2 \pi)^{2}} q^{11/3}|{\xi}|^{2}\right]
$

So the process is gaussian in a functional sense. I understand, that it is always possible to make your model discrete and manually simulate the process, but is there some built-in instrument in Mathematica, which allows you to deal with such things?

Thank everyone in advance!

Comment: Would you add your second equation in terms of *Mathematica* code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure how to do it, for the reason that Mathematica (at least to my knowledge!) doesn't support defining functionals, which maps some $f(x)\mapsto a\in \mathbb{R}$. This is one of the problems that my question motivated by.

Comment: it's easy to define functionals! consider `P[xi_]:=Exp[-Integrate[(1/(2Pi)^2)Norm[{q0,q1}]^(11/3)xi[{q0,q1}, t]*Conjugate[xi[{q0,q1}, t]], {q0,-Infinity,Infinity}, {q1,-Infinity,Infinity}, {t,-Infinity,Infinity}]`, but I'm not sure what $q^{11/3}$ is or what the bounds are, so I gave it my best guess. (one can also implement more traditional notation like `P[xi[{q0,q1},t]]` with a bit more effort.) But a path integral...hmmm. do you want it numerically?

Comment: (sorry, there's a missing closing `]` there)

Comment: also, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding—what's the *type* of thing you want to be the value of the random sample here? i.e., what should the random sample actually generate? a whole function?